# How to run a code from a particular country

Tags: php, geolocation, user-agent

I am trying to access data of an e-commerce website of another country. The problem is that different data is displayed in different countries. I want to access the data from the UAE. My server is in the USA and I guess the data is fetched as if my application is running the code from outside UAE. How do I make it look like it runs from UAE.

I am fetching this data using the following code

```
<?php
    $link = 'https://www.amazon.ae/Huawei-P20-Pro-Dual-SIM/dp/B07MMQRNYT/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=huawei&qid=1557457063&s=electronics&sr=1-3';
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" . 
              "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36\r\n"
            // 'ignore_errors' => true
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $html = file_get_contents($link, false, $context);
    echo $html;
?>
```

Can I set my code to run from UAE? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the [geolocation http header](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-geopriv-http-geolocation-00.html)?

Comment: @Trebor How do I add a geolocation HTTP header to the above code( I have updated the question with the code)

Comment: @Abdulla Questions about [coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here. Your other related question was migrated to Stack Overflow for the same reason, which is the proper site for asking code related questions on.